# How to get all characters except the last one in a bash script?

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I have a text file which contains filenames and labels to this files

**Example String:**
`0-3081031014094495-0.png 0`

I am using this command to iterate over the text file and get last char.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo $line | tail -c 2
done <$PWD/$i/caffe/test.txt
```

I also want to get everything before the last char. 
Something like `echo $line | head -c -2` which I interpret as:
*start from the beginning and get everything until the two last chars*

**Edit:**

Thank you for so many really fast answers. Something I did not mention in the original question was that I am using a mac. I thought it would not matter, but trying some of your answers I realized that it matters.

For example using negative substrings is [not supported](https://superuser.com/questions/1033273/bash-4-3-substring-negative-length-on-os-x) on mac.
James Brown solution was the first which worked for me, so thats why I accepted his answer.

Comment: _get last char_ - - _also - - get everything before the last char_ So, what is the expected output for that input?

Comment: Show us a minimal example input(file) and expected output needed

Comment: My expected output with this will be a file where I rearange the two parts and add some other information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To *get everything before the last char* in bash:

```
$ foo="0-3081031014094495-0.png 0" 
$ echo ${foo%?}
0-3081031014094495-0.png
```

From http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html :

${string%substring}

Deletes shortest match of *$substring* from back of *$string*.

Answer (score 1):

from `man head` and `man tail`

```
# head
   -c, --bytes=[-]K
          print the first K bytes of each file; with the leading `-', print all but the last K bytes of each file

# tail
   -c, --bytes=K
          output the last K bytes; alternatively, use -c +K to output bytes starting with the Kth of each file
```

Examples

```
$ tail -c -2 <<< 'hello world!'
!
$ head -c -2 <<< 'hello world!'; echo
hello world
```

However last char and all except last char can be obtain more efficiently with shell expansion

```
$ line='hello world!'
$ echo "${line:${#line}-1}"
$ echo "${line:0:${#line}-1}"
```

Answer (score 1):

If your input is space separated and the file names cannot contain spaces, `read` by itself is sufficient.

```
while read -r filename label; do
    printf "filename: %s label: %s\n" "$filename" "$label"
done <"$PWD/$i/caffe/test.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to use rev(1), i.e.:

```
$ echo "$line" | rev | cut -c 1 | rev
0
```

You can also pass line length to cut, i.e.:

```
$ echo "$line" | cut -c ${#line}
0
```

Or to cut few last chars:

```
$ echo "$line" | cut -c $((${#line} - 2))-
g 0
```